# Published my ASP.Net 2013 Website to IIS 7 and receiving an error of Invalid attemp to read data when no data is present

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I cannot seem to find out why my SQL data connections are not being recognized and the SQL Data Reader is not being able to read data when I publish my ASP.Net Site.  It works when I just use the localhost and it is not published but once I publish it to IIS 7 it can no longer read data from SQL server.  Please anyone if you can help that would great.  I am very new to IIS 7 and cannot figure this out for the life of me.  I have tried to check other blogs but I am coming up with nothing.  The error that I am getting is:

Invalid attempt to read when no data is present. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckDataIsReady(Int32 columnIndex, Boolean      allowPartiallyReadColumn, Boolean permitAsync, String methodName) +5327847
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn) +47
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i) +31
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i) +73
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name) +27
GLIncidentRequestForm._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +318
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

web.config connection string:

Page Code:

```
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NPXL_REPORTINGConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string strAccount = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
        string strUserName = strAccount.Split('\\').Last();
        txtStrName.Text = strUserName;

        string selectSQL = "SELECT sAMAccountName, mail FROM ActiveDirectories WHERE mail Is Not Null and sAMAccountName = '" + txtStrName.Text + "'";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = default(SqlDataReader);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();


            txtADName.Text = reader["sAMAccountName"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = reader["mail"].ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Post that code that calls your DB

Comment: OK I posted the code above.

Comment: Can you post your connection string?

Comment: <add name="NPXL_REPORTINGConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"    connectionString="Data Source=NYSQL2;Initial Catalog=NPXL_REPORTING;User ID=**********;Password=****"/>

Comment: OK, I posted my connection String.  And the configuration string to access it on my page.